# Android Studio/Gradle: set Java target version for Java Library module

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I want to set up `targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` for my Java Library in Android Studio (my jdk is 1.8). Just writing that assignment in lib's `build.gradle` fails: when I try to run resulting jar, I still get `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`. How should I define `targerCompatability` or other properties (i. e. main class for jar)?

Original `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
}
```

I am editing the right file since Android Studio uses that and actually builds and runs my code.

Edit: running error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/ldvsoft/warofviruses/WarOfVirusesServer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Edit: the code I have problems with is still in really bad state, and it's not on my github yet, don't look there.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please, go to menu in your IDE

```
**File - Other Settings - Default Project Structure - SDK Location**
```

and then set correct java sdk location (point to Java 1.8)